# Fake static/singleton class/method using microsoft fakes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes, vs-unit-testing-framework

I have class which has private constructor and accessed through public static method ( singleton class). Not able to create singleton object of this class in fakes.

```
public class MyBusinessManager : BusinessManager
{
 private MyBusinessManager objMyBusinessManager;

 private MyBusinessManager (MyBusinessManager dvqsDataManager)
        {
           objMyBusinessManager= dvqsDataManager;
        }
 public static MyBusinessManager GetInstance() // out
        {
            MyBusinessManager dvqsDataMgr = new MyBusinessManager();

            return new MyBusinessManager (dvqsDataMgr);
        }

 public bool MyBusinessManagerMethod (int bm)
       {
              if(bm == 0)
                 return true;

              return false;
       }
 }
```

I want to Test Following method:

```
public class MyService
{
   public bool MyServiceMethod(int serviceParam)
   {
        MyBusinessManager dvqBusinessManager = MyBusinessManager.GetInstance(); // make fake call
        return dvqBusinessManager.MyBusinessManagerMethod(serviceParam); // make fake service call
   }
}
```

My Test class:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyService_UT
{
  [TestMethod]
  public void TestMethod1()
  {
      using (ShimsContext.Create())
      {
        ShimMyBusinessManager.GetInstance = () => { return new ShimMyBusinessManager(); };
        ShimMyBusinessManager.AllInstances.MyServiceMethodInt32 = (a) =>{
                               return true;
                                 }
       MyService obj = new MyService();
       Assert.IsTrue(obj.MyServiceMethod(1))// doesn't call fake method
       }
  } 
}
```

How to call fake method in this case? Unable to create instance of fake with this code.

Comment: You've just learned one of the reasons singletons are "an anti-pattern"

Comment: Correct. This is old code. But how to get out of this?

Comment: It might be easier to refactor the crappy old code instead of putting another layer of crappy code on top to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to move creation of `dvqBusinessManager` outside of the method.

This way

```
    MyBusinessManager dvqBusinessManager = MyBusinessManager.GetInstance();
    public bool MyServiceMethod(int serviceParam)
    {
        return dvqBusinessManager.MyBusinessManagerMethod(serviceParam); // make fake service call
    }
```

Or

```
    public bool MyServiceMethod(int serviceParam)
    {
        MyBusinessManager dvqBusinessManager = MyBusinessManager.GetInstance();
        MyServiceTestableMethod(dvqBusinessManager, serviceParam);
    }

    public bool MyServiceTestableMethod(MyBusinessManager manager, int serviceParam)
    {
        return manager.MyBusinessManagerMethod(serviceParam);
    }
```

So you can inject a fake object to the method and test it, without calling `GetInstance` method.

Or you can implement and use a factory pattern and hide the static call there.

```
    public interface IServiceFactory 
    {
        MyBusinessManager GetInstance();
    }

    public class ServiceFactory : IServiceFactory
    {
        public MyBusinessManager GetInstance()
        {
            return MyBusinessManager.GetInstance();
        }
    }

    IServiceFactory factory = new ServiceFactory();
    public bool MyServiceMethod(int serviceParam)
    {
        MyBusinessManager dvqBusinessManager = factory.GetInstance();
        dvqBusinessManager.MyBusinessManagerMethod(serviceParam);
    }
```

But if you still want to mock a static call without changing the code, you should use Shims like in this example http://www.richonsoftware.com/post/2012/04/05/using-stubs-and-shim-to-test-with-microsoft-fakes-in-visual-studio-11.aspx.

Comment: Thanks. I have used code mentioned in the link to solve this issue.